# Is it possible to see only defined code except else in vim on linux?

Tags: vimrc

I'm trying to see the  verilog and systemverilog programing codes on linux by using VIM.

but some codes are defined with so many 'ifdef~'endif syntax.
so I'd like to see only the code related with define code within 'ifdef~'endif except else.

Is it possible to see only defined related code except else in VIM on linux?

Comment: Id look into `folding`, but I wouldnt know how to set it up for that case.